# Solving a math equation in excel through two variables

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
w=[1/mn(m^2+n^2)^2)]{sin(m*pi/2)sin(n*pi/2)}
```

where `m` and `n` varies from 1 to 11.

```
for m=1, n=1,3,5,7,9,11.
for m=2, n=1,3,5,7,9,11.
for m=3, n=1,3,5,7,9,11.
and so on.
```

Instead of 36 sets of combinations, I need one formula to calculate the set of these 36 combinations and get respective values of `w`.

Please help me with this equation. I need to solve it in excel.

P.S I'm beginner.

Answer (score 1):

You may create column and rows with heading values of n and m respectively, and calculate the value of w at their intersection. For auto-completion of formula by dragging, you will have to use `$` symbol for referencing. See the representation below:

```
m\n    1        3         5        7        9        11
1    w(1,1)   w(1,3)    w(1,5)   w(1,7)  w(1,9)    w(1,11)
2    w(2,9)   w(3,9) ... so on
3    ...
4
5
6
.
.
```

Instead of numbers above in w(m,n) use references of column while dragging with a `$` sign so that the header row does not change.

EDIT: You need to type the formula only once in at the intersection of (1,1)

Comment: i have created the column and rows as you showed.I also have defined my formula, but how do I link "m" and "n" values as (m,n) in my formula.

Comment: Type your formula at intersection of (1,1). Instead of typing the value of `m` and `n` select the respective values in the header. For e.g. if the formula is `1/m*n` and if header is `B1` for `n` and `A2` for `m` then you will type `1/($A2 * B$1)`. i.e replace m by $A2 and replace n by B$1. Now simply drag through the remaining rows and columns or copy-paste. Do not forget the `$` symbol

Comment: To understand what the $ signs mean search "absolute and relative referencing in Excel". Loads of explanations out there and one of the basics to learn for using Excel effectively.